# Failure to connect to configured mongo instance (Connection refused)

Tags: mongodb, docker

Based on this guide:

https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/install-simple-test-deployment/

I am installing MongoDB and MongoDB Manager. I have created a docker image for each application and start them on the same virtual network:

```
docker network create --driver bridge mongo-network
```

with:

**MongoDB:**

```
 docker run -ti -d --network mongo-network -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb-container mongodb-image
 docker exec -ti -u mongod mongodb-container "mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/appdb --logpath /data/appdb/mongodb.log --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 1 --fork"
```

And verified that its up and running with:

```
$  docker exec -ti -u mongod mongodb-container tail -f /data/appdb/mongodb.log

2019-04-21T15:26:05.208+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
2019-04-21T15:26:05.208+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
2019-04-21T15:26:05.208+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
2019-04-21T15:26:05.208+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
2019-04-21T15:26:05.208+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
2019-04-21T15:26:05.208+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
2019-04-18T06:23:35.268+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2019-04-18T06:23:35.269+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with provided UUID: c0736278-72ec-4dfc-893c-8105eefa0ba8
2019-04-18T06:23:35.320+0000 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 4.0
2019-04-18T06:23:35.341+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: local.startup_log with generated UUID: 397c17a3-3c5e-4605-b4dc-8a936dd9e40e
2019-04-18T06:23:35.394+0000 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/appdb/diagnostic.data'
2019-04-18T06:23:35.396+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
2019-04-18T06:23:35.397+0000 I STORAGE  [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] createCollection: config.system.sessions with generated UUID: ac7bdb6e-4a60-430f-b1a4-34b09012e6da
2019-04-18T06:23:35.475+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index on: config.system.sessions properties: { v: 2, key: { lastUse: 1 }, name: "lsidTTLIndex", ns: "config.system.sessions", expireAfterSeconds: 1800 }
2019-04-18T06:23:35.475+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh]     building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2019-04-18T06:23:35.477+0000 I INDEX    [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] build index done.  scanned 0 total records. 0 secs
```

**MongoDB Manager:**

```
  docker run -ti -d --network mongo-network -p 8080:8080 --name mongodb-manager-container mongodb-manager-image  
  docker exec -ti -u root mongodb-manager-container "/opt/mongodb/mms/bin/mongodb-mms start"
```

Below error message:

```
Generating new Ops Manager private key...
Starting pre-flight checks
    Failure to connect to configured mongo instance:Config{
       loadBalance=false,
       encryptedCredentials=false,
       ssl='false',
       dbNames='   [
          mmsdb,
          mmsdbprovisionlog,
          mmsdbautomation,
          mmsdbserverlog,
          mmsdbpings,
          mmsdbprofile,
          mmsdbrrd,
          mmsdbconfig,
          mmsdblogcollection,
          mmsdbjobs,
          mmsdbagentlog,
          mmsdbbilling,
          backuplogs,
          automationcore,
          monitoringstatus,
          mmsdbautomationlog,
          automationstatus,
          ndsstatus,
          cloudconf,
          backupdb,
          mmsdbprovisioning,
          mmsdbqueues
       ]   ',
       uri=mongodb://mongodb-container:27017/?maxPoolSize=150
    }Error:Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is{
       type=UNKNOWN,
       servers=   [
          {
             address=mongodb-container:27017,
             type=UNKNOWN,
             state=CONNECTING,
             exception=         {
                com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException:Exception opening socket
             },
             caused by         {
                java.net.ConnectException:Connection refused (Connection refused)
             }
          }
       ]
```

And for mongodb - based on suggestions below - I am now using:

**/etc/mongod.conf**:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  #bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0,::
```

and for MongoDB manager I am specifying the name of the mongodb container in:

**/opt/mongodb/mms/conf/conf-mms.properties**

```
#mongo.mongoUri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?maxPoolSize=150
#mongo.mongoUri=mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/?maxPoolSize=150
mongo.mongoUri=mongodb://mongodb-container:27017/?maxPoolSize=150
```

I have verified that I can **ping** `mongodb-container` from `mongodb-manager-container` with:

```
docker exec -it -u root mongodb-manager-container bash
[root@e23a34bf2161 /]# ping mongodb-container
PING mongodb-container (172.18.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mongodb-container.mongo-network (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.077 ms
64 bytes from mongodb-container.mongo-network (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from mongodb-container.mongo-network (172.18.0.2): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
^C
--- mongodb-container ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2042ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.052/0.062/0.077/0.013 ms
[root@e23a34bf2161 /]#
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Based on below suggestions I have now tried:

```
docker network create --driver bridge mongo-network
docker run -ti -d --network mongo-network -p 27017:27017 --name mongodb-container mongodb-image
# Copy modified version of mongod.conf file to container before starting mongodb    
docker cp mongod.conf mongodb-container:/etc/mongod.conf

docker exec -ti -u mongod mongodb-container "mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/appdb --logpath /data/appdb/mongodb.log --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 1 --fork"
docker run -it --rm --net container:mongodb-container nicolaka/netshoot ss -lnt
```

Which gives:

```
State    Recv-Q    Send-Q        Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port    
LISTEN   0         128              127.0.0.11:36001            0.0.0.0:*       
LISTEN   0         128               127.0.0.1:27017            0.0.0.0:*
```

Not sure if this is expected/good output and why I need to spin up container from the `nicolaka/netshoot` image...

**EDIT 2:**

As suggested below if I pass: `--bind_ip_all` on the command line for starting `mongod` it works:

```
docker exec -ti -u mongod mongodb-container "mongod --bind_ip_all --port 27017 --dbpath /data/appdb --logpath /data/appdb/mongodb.log --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 1 --fork"
```

So it seems when running as a docker container it completely ignores the **/etc/mongod.conf** file and you need to specify all the options in the docker exec command instead :-(

Comment: Can you check somehow, if your MongodDB container is correctly running? Like, is the database up and accessable e.g. from an application? Then I would guess, that the other docker container with the MongoDB manager don't has access to the MongoDB container.

Comment: I verified its up and running inside the container running mongodb using top and the logs - see updated post. I also set the docker network option on run for each container so they can connect.

Comment: Can you try setting bindIp: 0.0.0.0 in  /etc/mongod.conf ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, see updated post, but get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that it was ignoring the configuration in **/etc/mongod.conf** file. After googling e.g.:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36572

I found that you need to pass the `--config` parameter to `mongod` e. to get it to read the mongod.conf file e.g.:

```
mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

and with docker:

```
docker exec -ti -u mongod mongodb-container "mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf"
```

After doing the above I can now get it to listen on all interfaces with the below configuration in /etc/mongod.conf:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

DNS on the container name will resolve to the container ip. To connect to mongo on that name, even from inside the container, you need to have mongo listening on all interfaces:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0,::
```

Comment: I have tried that as well, see the updated post, but I get the same error.

Comment: @u123 Try running `docker run -it --rm --net container:mongodb-container nicolaka/netshoot ss -lnt` to debug whether mongodb is listening on all interfaces. And then run `docker run -it --rm --net container:mongodb-manager-container nicolaka/netshoot ping mongodb-container` to verify DNS and IP connectivity.

Comment: I have updated post with the first part you suggest - running the ss command from the container based on the nicolaka/netshoot image. Not sure what to conclude from the output I posted though.

Comment: @u123 the `127.0.0.1:27017` showing in the local listener port indicates the above configuration has not been applied. Did you run a build, rm, and run command?

Comment: Hm yeah it seems like it. But I copy over the updated mongod.conf file after the run command but before the start of the mongod process. And when I cat /etc/mongod.conf it contains the expected content. You are sure 'ss' can be used to list what mongod is listening on?

Comment: @u123, yes, the ss command is a newer version of netstat, it's showing what the application is actually doing. Try running your `mongod` command with `--bind_ip_all`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192182/discussion-between-u123-and-bmitch).

Answer (score 0):

You are running two separate containers and expect them to talk to each other over localhost? That never gonna work. You have to add "--link mongodb-container:mongo" to second docker run command and then use address mongodb://mongo:27017 in manager container.

Comment: No --link is deprecated, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/370300/why-some-dockers-use-docker-network-instead-of-the-link-parameter instead I am using the --network parameter, see details of the run commands in my post.